# Facing issue "The last status can't be unassigned from its current state" When we try to unassign a custom status from Order status grid

Tags: magento2.2, magento2-enterprise

When we try to unassign a status from a state in the sales status grid we are facing the following issue

```
The last status can't be unassigned from its current state
```

https://www.screencast.com/t/eD5btItqI

Anybody having idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this error message appearing due to unassign status which is the default one of the state, also that state doesn't have any more statuses.